# In React: Is there any equivalent of ScrollView in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making some cross-platform components for mobile web and app. For that use, I'd like to set a core that works as a view, and two implementations, one for web and another for app. In app side code, with React Native, I can use ScrollView component to make effects when scrolled, by using ref, onSCroll, onScrollBeginDrag, etc., that are only in ScrollView of ReactNative. Is there any modules, strategies or whatever I can use ScrollView in React for the use in web browser?

Comment: You can achieve all the things with the FlatList in react-native

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-slick library it is provides lots of features.